# Change the language setting in application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

How can I change the language setting in my application?

I need to add language setting functionality to the project.

Comment: Um, have you tried finding such a link?

Comment: Usually, once you implemented localization, your app would've follow your device's language in the first place. If you want to explicitly specify a language, you have to specify a bundle for your app, example if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(language, ofType: "lproj", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: language) {
            
            
            LocalizationHelper.bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
            
        }

Comment: Language is your language code specified in Xcode, as your file's name would be like "en.lprog"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// reading the language from the preferredLanguages in the bundle project architecture.
#define currentLanguageBundle [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"]]
#define CurrentNSLocalizedString(key) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, nil, currentLanguageBundle, @"")

// you can set language in the same location preferred settings like this :
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:lang forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
// lang can be : 
@"fr"
@"en"
@"de"
@"es"
@"it"
// etc ...
```

then you can call traduction of string configured on Localizable.Strings like this : `CurrentNSLocalizedString(@"my_text")`

And here are some links to use your Strings translations :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the language setting in your application. There are 2 solutions for consideration.

The first one is forcing the main bundle to load a specific locale source

.h

```
@interface NSBundle (HLanguage)
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "NSBundle+HLanguage.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface HBundle : NSBundle
@end

@implementation HBundle
-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (HLanguage)
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[HBBundle class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

This approach is a good and simple way, as you just add any supported localizations.

The second one is more flexible and allows you to support either language setting or contents driven, for example, with the same Eng locale, however, you want English in Germany will show the different content with English in Singapore. To put it simply, you create your own bundle resource, put all supported languages, then use `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` or `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` to specify "bundle" and "table" of the selected language.

Hope this would be helpful.